# Why are において・における necessary?

Tags: grammar, words

> 結果はホームページ**において**発表されます。
>
> 結果はホームページ**で**発表されます。

Both of these sentences seem to translate into "As for the result, homepage on will be posted," or more naturally, "The result will be posted on the homepage." What does において actually add to the sentence compared to when で is used?

Another example is shown below.

> ロンドン**における**国際会議が行われた。

This sentence translates into "The international conference took place in London." Can't the sentence be written just as well as "ロンドン**で**国際会議が行われた"? Again, what does おける add to the sentence?

(Example sentences taken from this [link](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-ni-oiteni-okeru/).)

Comment: Good question.  I can't explain it.

Comment: ロンドンに…行われた is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that using おける give a bit stiff, formal and literary impression. So it is often used in speeches and articles.

I think ロンドンにおける国際会議が行われた is unnatural, and ロンドンにおいて国際会議が行われた or ロンドンで国際会議が行われた would be natural.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Yuuichi Tam's answer, において・における are taking on the role that で would normally fill in these sentences, not に. The particle で is used when you are marking the location where an action takes place. However, において・における are more flexible than で, in that they can also be used for "non-physical" locations, like "in Japanese politics" or "in anime." So it is a flexible, formal way to play the role of marking the location of an action. It's common to see it on Wikipedia.

Comment: My usage of に instead of で was a slip-up. I've corrected it in my question. Thanks for pointing it out me.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, can you explain why my answer was incorrect or unhelpful? If I have misunderstood において in some way, I'd like to correct that misunderstanding, but I don't see anything wrong with it as it stands.